# How can I redirect an old long URL to a new SEO friendly URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an old URL :

```
www.mydomain.com/prodotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ..
```

to this one , shorter and SEO friendly:

```
www.mydomain.com/moto/aprilia/caponord_1200
```

I'm doing this writing a 301 redirect on `htaccess`, this is the line that I use:

```
 Redirect 301  /prodotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ.. http://www.mywebsite.com/moto/aprilia/caponord_1200
```

But when i insert on the browser the old URL the redirect result is :

```
  www.mywebsite.com/moto/aprilia/caponord_1200?/prodotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ..
```

What's is wrong in my 301 redirect? how can I obtain a pure redirect without URLs merging?

Thanks

this is the htaccess with a modrewrite test

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|media|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/moto/aprilia/capondor_1200$ /prodrotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ.. [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess should look like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^prodrotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ\.\.$ /moto/aprilia/capondor_1200? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|media|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works! thanks alot you save my night! or at least a good part :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a rewrite rule like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/moto/aprilia/capondor_1200$ /prodrotti/G/YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ [R=301]
```

You may need to replace `YToyOntzOjg6IklEX01BUkNBIjtzOjI6IjI3IjtzOjEwOiJJRF9NT0RFTExPIjtzOjM6IjU2OCI7fQ` in the rewrite rule the whole string, as I assume `..` means it's longer than what you provided?

Comment: thaks for your reply the double dots are a real part of the url (yeah it was an insane url :) ), i try your suggestion but i get an 500 error, I post on the question the complete htaccess